# How to can I see the allowed Whatsapp Business API solutions providers that have access to my Facebook Business?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, facebook-business-sdk

I'm looking inside the Facebook Business settings console but I does not have success.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Business Settings -> Users -> Partners. That will list the businesses and the corresponding assets that they have been provided the access to.